# Unsatisfied forward or external declaration? PictureContainer.pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a specific problem in Delphi 7, I am trying to run a custom application that was created by an outside party, so in a sense I am the free lancer trying to fix bugs and so on.

The problem: Unsatisfied forward or external declaration

This relates to the TMS Component Pack v5, the file I am having the problem with is `PictureContainer.pas`.

This is the error I am getting:

> [Error] PictureContainer.pas(135): Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'THTMLPicture.GetStretched'
>
> [Error] PictureContainer.pas(136): Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'THTMLPicture.SetStretched'
>
> [Error] PictureContainer.pas(188): Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'THTMLPictureCache.Destroy'
>
> [Fatal Error] HTMLStatusBar.pas(29): Could not compile used unit 'PictureContainer.pas'

I have been trying to find solutions for this and there is alot of them but at this point I am abit lost with this one as I have little understand of this type of error.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Here is the relevant extact of the source code for PictureContainer.pas:

```
unit PictureContainer;

{$I TMSDEFS.INC}

interface

//CUT

type
   //NOTE: THTMLPicture is not defined in this unit, but we do have includes...
   {$I WIIF.PAS}

//CUT   

implementation

//CUT

{$I WIIMPL.PAS}

//CUT

{ TPictureCollection } Error line 135 <-------------
                       Error line 136 <-------------
function TPictureCollection.Add: TPictureItem;

//CUT    

constructor TPictureContainer.Create(AOwner: TComponent); Error line 188 <-------------
begin

//CUT
```

Comment: Have you spoken to the vendor? Have you looked at the source code yourself?

Comment: To the vendor? I have the source code open right now.

Comment: Which is PictureContainer.pas line 135?

Comment: I have just edited it now, scroll down or here:

Comment: procedure TPictureItem.SetPicture(const Value: THTMLPicture);
begin
  FPicture.Assign(Value);
end;

{ TPictureCollection } <------------------------

Comment: "The complete source code remains property of the author and may not be distributed, published, given or sold in any form as such." - I think you should remove the source code from your question.

Comment: It seems to me that you have got a mismatching set of packages and associated files installed. Again, I think you should contact the vendor.

Comment: Then the way to fix is to uninstall Delphi 7 and then re-install it and make sure that I am installing the right packages and make sure they are installed correctly?

Comment: I decided to delete my answer. Rob's explanation should be sufficient. If you consider the error messages, it's blatantly obvious they have nothing to do with the lines of code the errors refer to. This is a clear indication the problem is somewhere else. If you examine the include files in the context of the error messages, you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: I noticed that the first time I tried to compile it. So then what I did was to include the WIIP.pas file under uses declaration as WIIP like so:          uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ComObj, ActiveX, WIIP        as when I do that I have multiple erros in that WIIP.pas file, not structured in a proper class format.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, although `WIIP.pas` is named PAS it's not really a PAS file, so you will get a bunch of errors if you use it as such. The convention is to name such files `.inc`. The way includes work is basically like copy-pasting the contents of the include file in place of the `{$I SomeFile.inc}`. You can do this to track your error.

Comment: @Vincent Deleting the copyright notice doesn't make you innocent of copyright violation. I'll edit the source-code to get to the heart of the problem.

Comment: True it does not, but that ended about 2005 and I did buy the TMS Component Pack that contains that pas file.

Comment: @VincentEnglish Interesting how you treat the copyright. The copyright "2001-2005" means **since** and not **from-until** and you simply cannot buy copyright

Comment: @Sir Rufo, Thank you for correcting me, I didn't know that. My thinking of the data as '2001-2005' was from-until, my mistake. But it is not my intention to steal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the compiler says "unsatisfied forward or external declaration," it means that somewhere in your code is a declaration of a function, but that it could not find that function's definition. Functions require definitions.

In your case, the missing implementations are for two methods of `THTMLPicture` and one of `THTMLPictureCache`. They're obviously not present in the code you've provided so far, so the compiler is right to complain.

There are a few possible solutions to this kind of error:

- Find the implementations and make sure the compiler can find them, too. Perhaps the implementations exist in the source code, but they're somehow excluded due to some `$IFDEF` expression that's become obsolete. Or maybe the compiler can't find some file that's meant to be incorporated via a `$INCLUDE` directive.
- Determine that the undefined methods aren't really needed, and delete their declarations. The compiler won't complain about missing definitions when it doesn't know about the declaration.
- Implement them. This is usually the solution when the error appears in your own code, because it usually indicates that you've forgotten to finish writing your program before you tried running it.

Comment: That's all good and well, but the thing is that you can get these types of pas files from the internet or from the TMS Component Pack depending on the version you have. This PictureContainer.pas file works with WIIF,pas, WIIMPL.pas and then once, let say it compiles, it connects to the HTMLStatusBar.pas.

Comment: Actually I think this hits the nail on the head. There are a few includes in this unit. In particular `{$I WIIF.PAS}` probably defines `THTMLPicture`. And `{$I WIIMPL.PAS}` fails to define the implementation. As a tip, overuse of includes like this will make code maintenance more difficult.

Comment: Yes, you can get those files from the Internet. I don't see what the source of the code has to do with the problem, though. Could you elaborate? You said your obstacle was that you "have little understand of this type of error." I've now explained what the error means. If that's not really your problem, then please refine your question to make it clear.

Comment: Yes you have answered that part of my question Rob. Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent The way includes work is basically like copy-pasting the contents of the include file in place of the `{$I SomeFile.inc}`. You can do this to narrow down on your error. However, I'd strongly recommmend refactoring this code to not be so reliant on includes.